# C# - Using Azure Key Vault with Azure Storage on Native App

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-keyvault

I'm using the following code to upload to my image container in my Azure storange account. The connection string in app.config is:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="MyConnectionString" />
</appSettings>
```

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("imagestorage");
// Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("IMG1.png");            
// Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"D:\Untitled.png"))
{
   blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
}
```

Question is how do I intergrate Azure Key Vault into my native application so that my API keys will not be compromised by some annoying reverse engineers?

I've registered my app in Azure Active Directory and given permissions for Azure Key Vault.

Also, who ever tries to use my native desktop app has to log in to my ASP.NET Web API app with Individual Accounts and receive a token, before using any other features. All of my controllers require authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to do is integrate your Azure KeyVault with your C# Application. You can do this my using 2 API. One being the Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault and the other being ADAL.

Following these steps may get you answer:

```
public async Task<string> GetToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
{
 var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientID"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"]);
        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);
        if(result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT Token");

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Retrieved Password");
        return result.AccessToken;
}
```

And then get the value of what you're trying to return by running this:

```
public async Task getvaluesAsync()
{
var kv = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetToken));
        var sec = await kv.GetSecretAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecretURI"]);
        EncryptSecret = sec.Value;
}
```

Replace the appropriate values of ClientID, Client Secret and SecretURI with your values in the App.config file. Use a getter and setter method with the "EcryptSecret" by doing something like,

```
public static string EncryptSecret { get; set; }
```

This will continuously store the password / DB connections for further use.

A few helpful articles would be:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-developers-guide

Comment: Is this answer still correct? I see that you expect to have the client secret in your app config but where do you get it? I haven't seen that documented anywhere and I think that method may have been removed for desktop apps

Comment: Hey Tim, As far as I'm still aware, I'm aloud to use it in a desktop application in which I built a while ago. However, this was a WPF application which I'm not sure makes any difference or not.